# Windows Forms equivalent code for the following code WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, forms, import

I have a small problem, I have the following WPF code and I try to import in Windows Forms. 
Here is the WPF code :

[image]

And here I try to modify the WPF code to make it functional in Windows Forms :

[image]

So, at pictureBox1.Image = bframe  I get the following error : "Cannot implicity convert type 'Systems.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame' to 'System.Drawing.Image' " . It's the first time I deal with WPF so I need a little help. Thanks .

Here's the code, sorry for the pictures :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog objDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        objDialog.Filter = "Only JPG File|*.jpg";
        objDialog.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = objDialog.FileName;
        Uri path = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
        BitmapFrame bFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(path);
        ViewedPhoto.Source = bFrame;
        ExifMetaInfo objMetaInfo = new ExifMetaInfo(path);
        lblBrand.Content = objMetaInfo.EquipmentManufacturer;
        lblModelName.Content = objMetaInfo.CameraModel;
        lblAparature.Content = objMetaInfo.LensAperture;
        lblCreation.Content = objMetaInfo.CreationSoftware;
        lblFocalLength.Content = objMetaInfo.FocalLength;
        lblHeight.Content = objMetaInfo.Height;
        lblWidth.Content = objMetaInfo.Width;
        lblISO.Content = objMetaInfo.IsoSpeed;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Drawing.Bitmap` instead of `BitmapFrame`. It has a constructor that takes a path.

In the future, please post the code here. I'd post a complete solution, if I could copy it and change just the one line, but I don't feel like typing all of it from a posted image.

Edit:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog objDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    objDialog.Filter = "Only JPG File|*.jpg";
    objDialog.ShowDialog();
    textBox1.Text = objDialog.FileName;
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(objDialog.FileName);
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Which System.Drawing.Bitmap property it's equivalent to Create () ?

Comment: As I wrote above, it's the constructor. Please be precise and use the correct words, Create() is a function or method, not a property.

Comment: I have the following error after modifying the text : "The best overloaded method match for 'system.drawing.bitmap.bitmap(system.drawing.image) ' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: I thought that if I fix this problem the rest of all will be easier but I do not manage to adapt the WPF code to Windows Forms . If I attach all the code you could please look over it for a second? 10x

Comment: Another question, It would be easier to integrate the wpf code into the winform application rather than modify line by line the wpf code?

Comment: Depends on your skill with both WPF and WinForms.